Mysql order by two columns separately
i would like to sort the result of a query so that 2 columns are sorted in ascending order. Both columns can contain the values 0 or NULL, which are then ignored for the sorting.
I don't know if I am expressing myself clearly.
Here is my query:
SELECT tripad_order, tourad_order
FROM(
    SELECT tripad_order, tourad_order
    FROM tripdetails 
    LEFT JOIN tripaddresses ON tripaddresses.trip_id = tripdetails.trip_id
    LEFT JOIN touraddresses ON touraddresses.tripad_id = tripaddresses.tripad_id AND touraddresses.tour_id = tripdetails.tour_id
    WHERE tripde_id = 39780

    UNION ALL

    SELECT tripad_order, tourad_order
    FROM tripdetails 
    LEFT JOIN touraddresses ON touraddresses.tour_id = tripdetails.tour_id 
    LEFT JOIN tripaddresses ON tripaddresses.tripad_id = touraddresses.tripad_id AND tripaddresses.trip_id IN (0,tripdetails.trip_id)
    WHERE tripde_id = 39780 AND tripad_type IS NOT NULL
) t
GROUP BY tripad_id
ORDER BY tourad_order

Here is the result



tripad_order
tourad_order




2
NULL


0
1


1
2


3
4


0
5



Here is the desired: result
tripad_order and tourad_order should both be arranged in ascending order, ignoring 0 and NULL



tripad_order
tourad_order




0
1


1
2


2
NULL


3
4


0
5




0 is normally sorted, and NULL is sorted as first, not ignored (using MySQL), see: https://dbfiddle.uk/dTjP8he-

How do you select 8 columns in you SQL query, and have a result with only two columns?

I have left out the other 6 columns in the result for the sake of clarity

In an [mre], you should leave out all non important stuff..... Just the basics to get a Reproducible Example

Current sort order is not clear tripad_order starts with 0, and ends with 0 ....

I have deleted everything that is not necessary from the code
Yes, that's how it should be, tripad_order and tourad_order should both be arranged in ascending order, with NULL and 0 as wildcards
tripad_order: x,1,2,3,x
tourad_order : 1,2,x,4,5

Please use [edit] to explain the logic of starting with 0, when sorting, and ending with 0. (for tripad_order).

GROUP BY tripad_id is not valid, since the subquery doesn't return that column.

"Both columns can contain the values 0 or NULL, which are then ignored for the sorting"  You cannot IGNORE a column when sorting. however the desired result can be achieved doing this (https://dbfiddle.uk/hBN_QdiU)  It still is not ignoring the 0 and/or NULL values.

You need to sort the columns tripad_order and tourad_order in ascending order, while treating 0 and NULL as special cases. To do this, you can use CASE statements in the ORDER BY clause to prioritize non-zero and non-NULL values first.
SELECT tripad_order, tourad_order
FROM (
    SELECT tripad_order, tourad_order
    FROM tripdetails 
    LEFT JOIN tripaddresses ON tripaddresses.trip_id = tripdetails.trip_id
    LEFT JOIN touraddresses ON touraddresses.tripad_id = 
     tripaddresses.tripad_id AND touraddresses.tour_id = tripdetails.tour_id
    WHERE tripde_id = 39780

    UNION ALL

    SELECT tripad_order, tourad_order
    FROM tripdetails 
    LEFT JOIN touraddresses ON touraddresses.tour_id = tripdetails.tour_id 
    LEFT JOIN tripaddresses ON tripaddresses.tripad_id = 
    touraddresses.tripad_id AND tripaddresses.trip_id IN (0, 
     tripdetails.trip_id)
    WHERE tripde_id = 39780 AND tripad_type IS NOT NULL
) t
GROUP BY tripad_order, tourad_order
ORDER BY 
    CASE WHEN tripad_order = 0 THEN NULL ELSE tripad_order END,
    CASE WHEN tourad_order IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, 
    tourad_order;

We use CASE WHEN tripad_order = 0 THEN NULL ELSE tripad_order END to treat 0 values as NULL, so they appear last when sorting tripad_order. Secondary Sort by tourad_order, prioritizing non-NULL values: CASE WHEN tourad_order IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END makes NULL values appear after non-NULL values in tourad_order. After that, tourad_order is sorted in ascending order.
Full explanation found on the link
https://admirable-smakager-729141.netlify.app/post/6

Please remove the external link. (What purpose does it serve?) And add some explanation to your query

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Just an edit to change full to Full will not do.... (https://stackoverflow.com/posts/79172984/revisions)

P.S. I am using a DARK theme under windows, and your website looks like this (using Edge): https://i.sstatic.net/rUfHRszk.png
